# Group by time that spans 2 days

Tags: mysql, sql, grouping

I am trying to get the month sales for a business where the time they are open is from 11am-2am the next day.  I tried doing the following by grouping each day assuming that just for worse case they do sales until 3am.  Assuming this is 16 hours of sales.  I haven't checked if the total is correct yet but I do notice that it only gives me back 29 days where there are 31 days in January.  a_invoices is the master invoice for each and a_tabs is the details for each invoice.

Am I doing this correctly?  I know basic MySql and this is a bit out of my pay grade.  Thanks for any help.

```
SELECT DATE(a_invoices.startdate - INTERVAL 16 HOUR) as day , sum(a_tabs.Total)
FROM a_invoices
Right JOIN a_tabs on a_invoices.TabId = a_tabs.TabId
WHERE a_invoices.closedate BETWEEN '2022-01-01 11:00:00' and '2022-01-30 03:00:00'
AND a_invoices.status='c' and a_tabs.status<>'v'
GROUP BY day
```

Comment: *the time they are open is from 11am-2am the next day.* Simply substract 11 hours and check the time from 0 AM till 3 PM of current day.

Comment: I can't just group by day because I will not get the correct figures for the exact day .  Saturday would have 12-2am from friday and the numbers will not help me see the correct values.  it is a bar and I need exact $$$ to determine what the night did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written from the 1st to the 30th. Try from the 1st to the 1st. It will also be easier to update the query each month

```
SELECT DATE(a_invoices.startdate - INTERVAL 16 HOUR) as day , sum(a_tabs.Total)
FROM a_invoices
Right JOIN a_tabs on a_invoices.TabId = a_tabs.TabId
WHERE a_invoices.closedate BETWEEN '2022-01-01 11:00:00' and '2022-02-01 03:00:00'
AND a_invoices.status='c' and a_tabs.status<>'v'
GROUP BY day
```

Comment: it was not him, surely, but it is a trivial typo error and is a close vote ground